# Python : ImportError: cannot import name X

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on IPython notebook. I've seen many similar errors on Stackoverflow as my error, but I can't see a solution that applies to my particular problem. I'm trying to use the Image module to convert a color image to a gray-scale image. But I get the following error.

```
import Image
from bisect import bisect
import random

im = Image.open('Lenna.png')

aspect = im.size[0] / float(im.size[1])
height = 128
im=im.resize((int(height*aspect), height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im=im.convert("L") # convert to mono
im.size
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2027dc6c0b02> in <module>()
----> 1 import Image
      2 from bisect import bisect
      3 import random
      4 
      5 im = Image.open('Lenna.png')

C:\Users\Tracking\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     27 from __future__ import print_function
     28 
---> 29 from PIL import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
     30 
     31 import warnings

ImportError: cannot import name VERSION
```

Comment: Do you have a file called PIL.py in your working directory?

Comment: How about use `from PIL import Image` instead of `import Image` ?

Comment: No, PIL.py is not in my working directory. I think PIL.py would be in a library path.

Comment: `from PIL import Image` causes the same error.

Comment: Maybe it's because your `PIL` Module is not installed fully, try to re-install it. Check the `PIL` lib folder `C:\Users\Tracking\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL` to see if there is a file named `VERSION.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was true when this post was made, but right now the error that is mentioned can be reproduced if the original PIL library was installed instead of the [pillow library](https://python-pillow.github.io/) (I found this post because I ran into the same error trying to install [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si)).

To get around it I removed the original:

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

Then installed pillow:

```
pip install pillow
```

I also installed all the dependencies (since I'm using a virtualenv) in ubuntu:

```
apt-get build-dep python-pillow
```

For orange specifically I then had to re-run the build_ext command:

```
python setup.py build_ext -f
```

And then the tests passed:

```
xvfb-run python setup.py test
```

(I used `xvfb-run` because I'm running it over ssh.)